# Can't shutdown when logged in with an administrator account

Tags: shutdown, users

While shutting down **Ubuntu 11.10** it returns to the Users menu, and remains there.

The problem is only when I am using an administrator account. I have to go back to a guest account to completely shut down the computer.

I am using a **Dell Inspiron Mini 1018**.

Answer (score 1):

1. check if any other user is logged in
2. check if you have any virtual machine still running (usually kvm/qemu have this behavior)
3. in the users menu you have an option at the right upper side to shutdown. Have a try at it.

Comment: To improve your answer, could you add how to perform step 1.?

Answer (score 1):

kamil is right - you can't shut down if there are other users (even guest) logged in.  To force a shutdown even if there are other users logged in issue the command

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

This will lose any data if there is an open application that has data that is not saved.  I haven't tested this with running VMs but I believe it will still work.